# live.users.enabled=true property and AutoLoginFilter in liferay 6.1.1

Tags: liferay

I want to monitor live users session in `liferay`. I found the solution for that need to put the property `live.users.enabled=true`  in portal-ext.properties file. By that We can see the live user sessions from Control Panel->Portal->Monitoring tab of liferay server. But if try to call **jsonws** for login purpose from mobile application it give me error of AutoLoginFilter. The error is as below :

```
07:57:46,519 ERROR [bio-http-'8080'][AutoLoginFilter:238] Current URL 
/sample-portlet/api/secure/jsonws?parameterAutoLoginLogin=test@liferay.com&
parameterAutoLoginPassword=test&j_username=test@liferay.com&j_password=test : 
generates exception : Session already invalidated
```

I am able to login in liferay from browser with same credentials. 
I figure out some issues that AutoLoginFilter not working when property live.users.enabled=true . One of them is here https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29871 .

So I want to monitor the live users sessions and AutoLoginFilter is work correctly. How can i achieve that. Please give me solution if any one can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook the Autologin filter in this case. Remove following snippet from the **getLoginRemoteUser** method. (line 94)

```
else if (PropsValues.LIVE_USERS_ENABLED) {
        UserTracker userTracker = UserTrackerLocalServiceUtil.fetchUserTracker(userId);

   if ((userTracker == null) && (session.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER) == null)) {
         session.invalidate();
         return null;
    }
}
```